# incompatible pointer type errors when adding * to user defined type

Tags: c, debugging

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "textbuffer.h"

typedef struct textNode{ //basically contains a line + link
    char* line;
    int sLength; //length of string
    struct textNode* next; 
} tNode; 

struct textbuffer{
    int size; //number of lines in the text buffer
    tNode* head; 
    tNode* tail;
}

static tNode* newTN(char* string, int sLength, tNode* next);

static tNode* newTN(char* string, int sLength, tNode* next){
    tNode* t = malloc(sizeof(struct textNode));
    t->line = malloc(sizeof(char)*sLength);

    if(string != NULL){
        strcpy(t->line, string);
    } 
    t->next = next; 
    return t;
}

static void printBuffer(TB tb){
    tNode* curr = tb->head;
    int i = 0;
    while(curr != NULL){

        while(curr->line[i] != '\n'){
            printf("%c", curr->line[i]);
            i++;
        }
        printf("\n");
        i = 0;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}

/* Allocate a new textbuffer whose contents is initialised with the text given
 * in the array.
 */
TB newTB (char text[]){

    assert(text != NULL); 

    int i = 0; 
    char c;

    TB tBuffer = malloc(sizeof(struct textbuffer)); 
    tBuffer->size = 0; 

    //tNode* currLine = malloc(sizeof (struct textNode*));
    tNode* currLine = newTN(NULL, 1, NULL);
    tNode* currtNode; 

    //currLine->line = malloc(sizeof(char));
```

I keep getting errors when assigning things like "curr = curr->next", and the first error I get is:

expected '=', ',', ';','asm' or '**attribute**' before token '*' in the line where I declare my static function newTN. Please tell me what the problem is...thanks...so confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In definition of `typedef struct textNode` you have declared `struct textNode** next` i.e. `next` is `pointer-to-pointes` or `double pointer`. But in function `static tNode* newTN(char* string, int sLength, tNode* next);` you have declared `next` as `single-pointer`.

So, in line `t->next = next;` of function `static tNode* newTN(char* string, int sLength, tNode* next);` you can not assign `single-pointer` to `double pointer`.

To solve this issue, declared `struct textNode** next` in `typedef struct textNode` as `struct textNode* next` i.e. as `single-pointer`.

**Updated:**
Definition of `struct textbuffer` is not terminating with `;`.

Comment: thanks yes i saw that but im still getting this error:

expected '=', ',', ';','asm' or 'attribute' before token '*' in the line where I declare my static function newTN.

also i edited the double pointer out shortly after posting.

Comment: @GCGSAUCE Definition of `struct textbuffer` is not terminating with `;`. I have updated the answer for the same.